# Is there an elegant way to delete a widget in QScrollArea in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I am learning PyQt5 recently and have problems when I want to delete a widget in `QScrollArea`. Is there an elegant way to visit the element in `QScrollArea` and delete it when the "delete" button in that element is clicked? Thank you for any help!

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(QPlainTextEdit(id))
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Delete'))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # connect options
        connect_options()
    

    def connect_options(self):
        pass


class MyList(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        for x in range(10):
            self.layout.addWidget(MyWidget(str(x)))
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setMinimumSize(1024, 500)
        self.setWidget(self.widget)
```

Comment: "[I] have problems when I want to delete a widget". What problems? There's no attempt in deleting in your code.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear, I have added the supplement information.

Comment: The recursion error is pretty clear (you know what recursion is, right?): you're calling `self.delete()` *from* `self.delete()`, what were you expecting to get from there? Then, what do you mean by "visit the "Delete" button widget elegantly"?

Comment: ...Yeah, I didn't notice that my function has the same name with that of PyQt. Thank you for your help. By "visit the delete button elegantly", actually I can visit that widget by index, but things get complex when the list grows longer, so I wonder if there is a way to visit it by the text content of that button.

Comment: If by "visit" you mean "access", then you can just store the object in a data container such as a list or a dictionary. About the recursion, that was *your* function (there's no `delete()` in Qt), it would have been the same if you'd called it "whatever": if you declare a function with `def whatever(self):` and in that function you call `self.whatever()` you have an infinite recursion, because you're calling the function from itself. I strongly suggest you to *study* what [classes and instances](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) are and how they work.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest you look into QListWidget, It will provide you various functions to handle situations like this.

for your problem, you will need to delete the widget from its parent layout & then delete it from the GUI

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, id):
       super().__init__()
       self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
       self.layout.addWidget(QPlainTextEdit(id))
       del_btn = QPushButton('Delete') 
       del_btn.clicked.connect(self._delete) # connect the click event to your delete function
       self.layout.addWidget(del_btn)
       self.setLayout(self.layout)

       # connect options
       self.connect_options()


    def connect_options(self):
       pass

    def _delete(self):
       # here you will delete your widget
       parent_layout = self.parent().layout()
       parent_layout.removeWidget(self) # remove the widget from its parent layout
       self.deleteLater() # lets Qt knows it needs to delete this widget from the GUI
       del self
```